# View users who logged in during a specific time period using last

Tags: bash, command-line, last

What I'm looking to do is get a sorted list of all users that have logged in during a specific time frame (say, for example, since the start of September).

How would I specify a time frame (like my example) within the `last` command?

I'm also thinking the command `uniq` would be a good way to eliminate any duplicate users who have logged in.
Also, the `sort` command seems to be a good way to sort the list, like I'm wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `last` from util-linux, you may specify time ranges with `-s (--since)` and `-t (--until)`. Check `TIME FORMATS` section in [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/util-linux/last.1.en.html) for valid time specifications. I'll give some valid examples:

```
last -s "-1 week"
last -s "-3 days"
last -s "2020-09-01"
```